# Error "Class Locale Not found" in Yetiforce Installation

Tags: yeti

Good afternoon,
I tried to install the Yetiforce application through cPanel, but when I finished installing it and opened the URL, I got the error: "Class Locale not found"
I have modified the options in php as it says in the official documentation of Yetiforce, but the error continues.
Can someone tell me or explain how to fix it, please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve your problem you have to install / turn on PHP "intl" extension.
You can find this resolution on their github project page:
[Class Locale not found](https://github.com/YetiForceCompany/YetiForceCRM/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Class%20Locale%20not%20found)

**Overthere you have all server requirements:**
List of mandatory libraries you can find below "THIRD PARTY LIBRARIES CONFIGURATION".
https://yetiforce.com/en/knowledge-base/documentation/implementer-documentation/item/web-server-requirements